# Explaining what main script only runs if imported means?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, module, automated-tests

I am a little bit confused on what the teacher is asking for here. Can someone please explain what it means when main script should on run if module is executed?

This is what the instructions were:

Main script with automated testing. The main script should only run if the
module is executed. It should not run when the module is imported. The main
script should print the total number of tests that pass and fail.

In the textbook it gives an example like this:
[image: Txtbook Image]

Not really sure what is going on

Comment: When a module is imported, the top-level code is executed.  So for example if a module had `print("Hello")` at the topmost level, then that message would print when the module is imported.  Your teacher is asking you to make sure your module does not ask for input when it is _imported_, but only when it is _executed_.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

When you execute a python module as a script, it is only slightly different than when you import it as a module. Here's a quick way to illustrate the difference.

Say you have a file `module.py` with content:

```
print(__name__)
```

If you run the script directly it will say:

```
$ python module.py
__main__
```

If you instead import it from another script it will output:

```
$ python -c "import module"
module
```

You can see here, that if a python file is run as a script, that the `__name__` attribute will report `"__main__"`.

So if you want to only run code if the module is executed as a script then you can write:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   <code you want to execute as a script here>
```